# Proof of lemma $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq Mn^2 |x-y|$ used by Spivak to prove Inverse function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

How did we get the representation of $f^i(x)-f^i(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a telescoping sum 
$$
a_n-a_0=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j-a_{j-1}
$$
where
$$
a_0=f^i(x_1,…,x_n)\text{ and }\\
a_j=f^i(y_1,…,y_j,x_{j+1},…,x_n).
$$